# tensorflow is not importing even after successful installation in centos

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6wjT.png)
hi freinds in Centos 6.9 i am unable to import tensorflow-1.3.0 in any anaconda (2,3) and getting this error please resolve this issue ..

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow - please read this to learn how to ask questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you installed glib and glibc?